# Python output just shows blinking cursor

Tags: python, ide, terminal

I recently started messing around with python and I wrote a program to print out the 1000th prime number but the output only shows a blinking cursor , the code is shown below:

```
number = 3
count= 1

while count <= 1000:   
          prime = True
          for x in range(2, number):
          if number % x == 0:
               prime= False
          if prime == True:
               count = count + 1
          if count <= 1000:
               number = number + 1

print number
```

Any help and concise explanation would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you posted the [*exact* code](http://ideone.com/s6FS0) that you use?

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you using IDLE?

Comment: @Tichodroma: your edit changed the meaning of the code. I've rollbacked it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks. Those broken indentions in some Python questions make reading (and editing) questions hard :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: i just realized the problem. @tichodroma solved the problem but did so by editing the OP post. so when i got to it it was already solved, how ever, he solved it by putting the print into the loop, hence the many numbers waterfall. but it should be outside the loop so as to only show the final result. also - after looking at the OP code before edit, it was written in such a way that it was taking a long time to run, and the "blinking line" was the system working in the background

```
def isprime(n):
    '''check if integer n is a prime'''
    # make sure n is a positive integer
    n = abs(int(n))
    # 0 and 1 are not primes
    if n < 2:
        return False
    # 2 is the only even prime number
    if n == 2: 
        return True    
    # all other even numbers are not primes
    if not n & 1: 
        return False
    # range starts with 3 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n
    # for all odd numbers
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

counter = 0
number = 0

while True:
    if isprime(number):
        counter+=1
    if counter == 10000:
        break
    number+=1

print number
```

Comment: the "isprime" code is from "http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216880/check-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-python" which was from a quick google search. but there are simpler methods to determine.

Comment: the question is not about how to find 1000th prime (in this case a simple [Sieve of Eratosthenes would be better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641098/interpreting-a-benchmark-in-c-clojure-python-ruby-scala-and-others#comment15487214_11641098)). The question is why the OP sees only blinking cursor.

Comment: when i ran the OP code, it started printing numbers from 3 increasing by 1 each time on a new line, until i stopped the code.

Comment: yes. That's why I've added [comment to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735357/python-output-just-shows-blinking-cursor/11735457#comment15573900_11735357).

Comment: true, i see that now, when i started looking to answer the question there were no comments.

Comment: i just realized the problem. @tichodroma solved the problem but did so by editing the OP post. so when i got to it it was already solved, how ever, he solved it by putting the print into the loop, hence the many numbers waterfall. but it should be outside the loop so as to only show the final result. also - after looking at the OP code before edit, it was written in such a way that it was taking a long time to run, and the "blinking line" was the system working in the background.

Comment: btw, `isprime` should probably return an error if it doesn't receive a positive integer as an argument otherwise it might hide an error in other parts of a program. On Python 2.x if `n` may be large than `xrange` should be used. `int(n**.5) + 1` should be replaced by `int(n**.5 + 1.5)` (check `n==3` case).

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian. I showed the exact code I used, the logic of the code seems right but why isn't it running

Comment: @InbarRose Rose the code you posted above does not actually work, and I actually want to know why my own code does not work.

Comment: @ Joel Corenett , Yes I'm using the IDLE

Comment: @Inbar Rose , you're right it takes a while to load, I just need to wait for 5 secs.