# How to return same list by using reduce function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, scheme, racket, reduce, fold

In DrRacket to return the list without changing by using foldr done this way:

```
(foldr cons '() '(1 2 3))
```

However in Clojure reduce is fold left so how can I do this?

First I tried this:

```
(reduce cons '() '(1 2 3))

=> IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

Afterward I tried this:

```
(reduce conj '() '(1 2 3))
=> (3 2 1)
```

"=>" is the output in REPL

No I don't want to read how Clojure implements reduce. I already know that. This is a more specific question. I found the answer myself, I will post it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we do both left and right folds in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800255/how-do-we-do-both-left-and-right-folds-in-clojure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I don't know how efficient it. We used this kind of solutions in University during Racket lessons.

```
(reduce #(concat %1 (list %2)) '() '(1 2 3))
=> (1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second attempt you had to "flip" the arguments passed to cons for things to work:

```
(reduce #(cons %2 %1) '() '(1 2 3))
=> (3 2 1)
```

However, as you noticed, reduce is actually a fold-left, so the first item in the original list, becomes the inner-most (or last) item in the result list. This could be handled with `reverse`:

```
(reduce (fn[a b](cons b a)) '() (reverse '(1 2 3)))
=> (1 2 3)
```

You can read more about why clojure 'lacks' foldr in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/MizwTxHwLE4)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Racket, but Clojure's `reduce` appears to differ from Racket's `foldr` in two major ways:

- `reduce` processes the list from head to tail (vs. tail to head for `foldr`).  In this respect, `reduce` is similar to `foldl`.
- `reduce` passes the accumulated value as the *first* argument to the reducing function (vs. the *last* argument for `foldr`/`foldl`).

The second difference is the reason for the error when using `cons` -- `(cons '() 1)` is the first call made, and `1` obviously isn't a list.

If we consider that `(conj xs x)` is equivalent to `(cons x xs)` when `xs` is a list, then `(reduce conj '() '(1 2 3))` is equivalent to `(cons 3 (cons 2 (cons 1 '())))` which might be more apparent when written as

```
(->> '()
     (cons 1)
     (cons 2)
     (cons 3))
```

Now, if you don't mind the result being a vector instead of a list, you could do:

```
(reduce conj [] '(1 2 3))
```

Or, if you prefer, you could convert the result into a `seq` so that it essentially behaves like a list:

```
(seq (reduce conj [] '(1 2 3)))
```

Alternatively, you could `reverse` the input list:

```
(reduce conj () (reverse '(1 2 3)))
```

Comment: `(list* xs)` is the same as `(seq xs)`. Neither is more listy than the other.

Comment: @amalloy Hmm, looks like you're right.  I guess you shouldn't base your understanding of a function solely on its name ;-)