# how to reduce in reverse so to iterate from the last index and on through until the 0 index?

Tags: clojure

I would like my anonymous function inside my reduce call to be able to operate on the list of input in reverse order. In javascript there is a function called .reduceRight() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight What is the equivalent in clojure?

Comment: Is it not feasible to just reverse the sequence first? Depending on the sequence you're reducing over, that would potentially be just as (in)efficient. Only sequences with constant random access would be able to do a right reduction efficiently.

Comment: Clojure Coding [Example](https://gist.github.com/kohyama/2893987), but internally it reverses the list prior to reduce.

Comment: See this answer for examples of `foldl` and `foldr` in Clojure, the latter is probably closer to what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775034/483566

Comment: Just reverse the sequence... `(defn reduce-right [f coll] (reduce f (reverse coll)))` (possible add `val` if needed)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Your comment is true for any reduce-right implementation. Its not a clojure-related constraint... So I doubt its a problem.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Except some languages like Haskell are better able to make use of right reductions do to them being lazier from what I understand.

Answer (score 2):

You want to *iterate from the last index and on through until the 0 index*. This suggests you are dealing with something like a vector. If so, you can apply the [`rseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rseq) function to it, which yields, in constant time, a reversed sequence of its argument.

Clojure's vectors have java class `PersistentVector`. This implements an interface called `Reversible`. This is what the `rseq` function looks for.